# write javassist proxy bytecode to .class file?

Tags: proxy, decompiling, javassist

I'd like to decompile a javassist proxy to understand what ProxyFactory.makeForwarder actually does. I see that it's possible to write class bytecode to an OutputStream from CtClass but cannot figure out how to create a CtClass if one starts with ProxyFactory.createClass() - mimicking how Hibernate uses javassist. Here's what I tried:

```
public void testProxyToDisk() throws Exception {
    ProxyFactory f = new ProxyFactory();
    f.setSuperclass(Product.class);
    f.setFilter(new MethodFilter() {
        public boolean isHandled(Method m) {
            // ignore finalize()
            return !m.getName().equals("finalize");
        }
    });
    Class<?> proxyClass = f.createClass();
    ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    ClassLoader classLoader = ProxyFactory.classLoaderProvider.get(f);
    classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(classLoader));
    CtClass ctClass = classPool.get(proxyClass.getName());  //barfs here    
    ctClass.debugWriteFile();
}
```

and here's the result.

> javassist.NotFoundException:
>   javassist.jassist_163.Product_$$_javassist_0  at
>   javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)   at
>   javassist.jassist_163.Find2MethodsPerfTest.testProxyToDisk(Find2MethodsPerfTest.java:36)

Test class and Product class are in the same package (javassist.jassist_163), fwiw. Thank you.

Comment: what is the final solution? please answer your own question, if you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

i should have been more patient: setting ProxyFactory.writeDirectory does the trick

Comment: After setting f.writeDirectory="e:/temp"; got the same error.

Comment: The error is about not able to find the proxy class, not where to write the class.